# When using axios interceptors I can't get an AxiosError instance inside a try and catch block

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, interceptor

When I use axios **interceptors** to log the user out when the error code is **401** I can't get any error code outside my **interceptor**. Let's suppose I have a **try** and **catch** block outside **axios interceptors**. So what happens is that I'm not able anymore to get an **AxiosError** instance in any **try** and **catch** block outside **axios interceptors**. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Below is my interceptor:

```
api.interceptors.response.use( (response: AxiosResponse) => response,

(error: AxiosError) => {

if (error.response?.status === 401) signOut();

},

);
```

Below is a catch and try block example (the result is **undefined**):

```
try {

} catch (err) {

console.log(err.response.status);

}
```

Comment: I solved throwing the error like this:

`api.interceptors.response.use(
    (response: AxiosResponse) => response,
    (error: AxiosError) => {
      if (error.response?.status === 401) {
        signOut();
      }
      console.log('throwing error');
      throw error;
    },
  );`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the Error too if you override the inspector's error, to allow to try catch detect error...

for example:

```
return error.response ? error.response : Promise.reject(new Error(error));
```

Inspectors Response Sample:

```
// Add interceptors for validate authorization
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    // do somthing if its needed
    // return response
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      // Re-request instance if refresh token updated successfully
      return instance.request(error.config);
    }

    return error.response ? error.response : Promise.reject(new Error(error));
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do "throw error;" like below.

```
api.interceptors.response.use(     
(response: AxiosResponse) => response,     
(error: AxiosError) => {       
   if (error.response?.status === 401) {         
     signOut();       
   }       
   console.log('throwing error');       
   throw error;     
},   );
```